# SQL Server database notification using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to perform some actions in my C# program whenever a record is inserted into SQL.
I used to do with `SqlDependency`. But now customer is asking us to do with `WCF` service.
Is is better to with `WCF` when compared to `SqlDependency`. Any link where to start with WCF?

Comment: Tell your client to mind their own business? What does WCF have to do with database monitoring? It is a service framework... Ask them what they expect WCF to do for them and see if you can deliver that, but WCF is not a SqlDependency replacement.

Comment: but they are asking to do with WCF. THey are telling SqlDependency is not reliable..

Comment: And they believe SqlDependency is not reliable why?  As @CodeCaster said, find out what is they really want, and then use the proper technology to resolve their concerns/problems.

Comment: Those two technologies are not comparable because they don't do the same things. That's like saying "knives are dangerous, use an orange instead". It just doesn't make sense.